# Linux freezes after a couple of minutes / hours, memtest freezes at 11% and 7% on the first test

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeze, memtest

I recently installed ubuntu desktop 20.04 on my machine which is otherwise running Windows 10 without a problem.

On Ubuntu it would randomly hang after minutes / hours. My first instinct was a memory issue, I currently have 48GB of memory installed (2x8GB and 1x32GB), what I noticed was that even the memtest would hang at 11% [image: memtest]

I then removed all combinations of memory sticks, but the only difference was that it would hang at a different test percentage. I also installed ubuntu server 20.04 but it seems to have the same issue.

I also installed new NVIDIA drivers, as I heard that this can be an issue, even though it seems weird that this would influence the memtest. No change.

How would I debug this ?

I found something about a crash in `/var/log/syslog` but I am not sure if this means anything.

```
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Succeeded.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu apport[894]:  * Starting automatic crash report generation: apport
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu grub-common[912]:  * Recording successful boot for GRUB
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu apport[894]:    ...done.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu grub-common[912]:    ...done.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: plymouth-quit-wait.service: Succeeded.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Hold until boot process finishes up.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: plymouth-quit.service: Succeeded.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Set console scheme...
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Set console scheme.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Aug  9 20:07:30 philipp-ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
```

I pasted the whole syslog [here](https://pastebin.com/Pa4cpR61)

Comment: To check if it's v. 20.04 causing the issue, you might try running a long-term service version, e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, from a USB flash drive (rather than immediately installing), to see if that version works better on your system.

Comment: check cpu load, might be indicator for software/os problem

Comment: Doesn’t the bootable MEMtest run on DSL?

Comment: DrMoishePippik: I can try that, I do not really mind installing it directly.

alecxs: Thats the weird one, I have it under heavy load sometimes, but it does not seem to be really tied to CPU load. I am not sure how to check the memtest for that but it seems to be weird that it would then always hang at the same spot right?

TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: I am not sure what DSL means ( damn small linux ? ) I am definitely running the bootable version of it.

Comment: `memtest` runs _below_ the OS. So, if you detect problems with memtest, it should be hardware. You stated you have tried removing all the  memory _sticks_ combinations. Try to use only one each time (if they have not to be paired) and try to use it in each slot. Some motherboards have a defined order to use their slots. If the problem still persist it should be the motherboard. (BTW the 20.04 one is a LTS, but memtest runs _below_).

Comment: Please add details of your computer, and especially the motherboard model and the RAM sticks.

Comment: Remove all memory & install just one stick & run memtest. Remove stick & mark good, bad, questionable, install another single stick, run memtest. Rinse, repeat. I'd also remove any un-necessary hardware during this: USB hard drive, USB thumb drive, maybe even unplug the internal HDD although memtest SHOULDN'T be accessing it

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Ubuntu 20.04 in Live USB  to see what append width, even if the freeze of memTest focuses you on a story of memory.
You can also redo this Memory test from the liveUSB.
But at least if the LiveUSB also freezes, you can be sure that the problem does not come from your installation *(here is obviously some "Docker" and co which starts at boot)*

if the liveUSB works correctly ... well you will know where the problem is ;)

EDIT: to take a closer look at your log, it "seems" that a container takes the "hand" and uses an old kernel.

You should also take a look at the Bios of your machine, some options are disabled which concerns, among other things, memory, but not only ...